# Graphic programming over video playback

Tags: c, user-interface, graphics, video, sdl

I want to make some GUI mockup program for video player, so my idea is just to show some menu pictures over real video being playback. I have working program made with C and SDL just to load pictures and make a slideshow, but i don´t know how to put this over video with transparencies.

Do you have a hint?

ps. i usually program with python and C, so if there is any solution with this two i highly appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: thanks, i will investigate this overlay issue, that will be useful to superimpose the images over the video.
But still pending how to play a video in some of the planes? there should be an easy way to do it, but i cannot find anything...

Comment: I'm just not sure whether you put video into the overlay surface then masked-blit over it, or whether you have to do some colour-key trickery where you basically masked-blit over a magenta background, so the hardware knows where to put video (where the magenta is) and where to leave your foreground graphics untouched.

Comment: The "overlay" basically *is* the video - not your foreground graphics. I guess your graphics are an overlay over an overlay ;-) - the video is overlayed over your apps window.

Comment: ok. i understand thanks.
But basically then i must somehow (maybe with ffmpeg) decode the video stream to individual images and then fliping it one after another, isnt? i find this very anoying, i wonder if some existing library will do that job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: use Openframeworks

http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation

It is in C++ though, and not C.

Check the documentation for class ofVideoPlayer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this tutorial, to get a working video player in SDL: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html

The tutorial is using SDL and ffmpeg. In the "tutorial 01", the video frame is converted to 24-bit RGB, so you can just do some tricks and translate to a surface.

If you want the overlay, you can see this library: http://www.libsdl.org/projects/sdlyuvaddon/

There is a function (Get_YUV_From_Surface) to convert a surface to YUV. You will need to modify it to fit your needs, but you can see the function to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You could render the video with OpenGL using a textured quad, and then do all your 2D drawing on top (with an appropriate 2D projection matrix setup) using GL.

- [SDL OpenGL support](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/Using_OpenGL_With_SDL)
- [Python OpenGL bindings](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/)

Depending on your codec, you are quite likely to end up with YUV data (rather than RGB).  Depending on the platform and your hardware, you may be able to use a native texture type, to avoid having to convert to RGB first.

By using alpha blending, you can easily come up with some very sophisticated looking UIs.  You will probably want to look into something like FreeType to handle the font rendering, as this is one area of GL that is platform-specific and fiddly to get working.

There are loads of tools, scene graphs, widget libraries and so on for OpenGL you can use too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gstreamer with both C/python.
all you have to do is to overlay a rendered video on a window.

Check out the doc of how to do it https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideooverlay.html?gi-language=c#GstVideoOverlay